# convert the below code from Oracle sql to Postgre sql

Tags: postgresql, oracle

```
select rownum,
    p.apple,c.apple,o.boy,o.cat,o.bat,d.goat,v.emp
    from other o
    inner join cast c on c.id=o.id
    inner join dept d on c.oid=d.oid
    left join posh p on p.pnum=o.onum
    left join valent v on v.vnum=o.onum
    start with o.vnum = ? connect by prior o.onum = o.vnum
    order by rownum desc;
```

Please need your inputs on converting the above code from Oracle to PostgreSQL, or a common code which supports both oracle and PostgreSQL.

Comment: Are you asking about `connect by prior`? That's an Oracle extension used for hierarchical queries. The standard equivalent is to use [recursive queries/CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE)

Comment: Please share your current research result and describe what is the issue with making the next step in query rewriting.

Comment: Hi astenx, this was my approach. I jsut removed all the joins and tables. still i am getting the below error. Also I am completely new to the post gre environment.
missing FROM-clause entry for table "cte"
with recursive cte
as (
 select 1 as level from scientist
 
 union all
 
 select cte.level + 1 from scientist
  
 )
select row_number() over (
  order by level desc
  ) as rownum

from cte
order by rownum desc;